# Bounded cumulative sum?

Tags: r

How can I do a cumulative sum over a vector (like `cumsum`), but bounded so that the summation never goes below a lower bound or above an upper bound?

The standard cumsum function would result in the following.

```
foo <- c(100, -200, 400, 200)
cumsum(foo)
# [1]  100 -100  300  500
```

I am looking for something as efficient as the base `cumsum` function. I would expect the output to look like the following.

```
cumsum.bounded(foo, lower.bound = 0, upper.bound = 500)
# [1]  100  0  400  500
```

Thanks

Comment: If your'e looking for a function as efficient as the base `cumsum` function, you have to implement it in `C`.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to adjust Rcpp's sugar function [cumsum](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/cumsum_8h_source.html) to your needs. As far as I see you'd only need to add one if statement.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein or more likely an `Rcpp` solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Rcpp` is a good way to go.

`cumsumBounded.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]                                                             
NumericVector cumsumBounded(NumericVector x, double low, double high) {
  NumericVector res(x.size());
  double acc = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    acc += x[i];
    if (acc < low)  acc = low;
    else if (acc > high)  acc = high;
    res[i] = acc;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Compile and use new function:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file="cumsumBounded.cpp")
foo <- c(100, -200, 400, 200)
cumsumBounded(foo, 0, 500)
# [1] 100   0 400 500
```

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this might work.

```
library ("Rcpp")

cumsum.bounded <- cppFunction(
    'NumericVector cumsum_bounded (NumericVector x, const double lower, const double upper) {

        double acc = 0;
        NumericVector result(x.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            acc += x[i];

            if (acc < lower) acc = lower;
            if (acc > upper) acc = upper;

            result[i] = acc;
        }

        return result;
    }')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of pure R versions.  Not likely to be as fast as going to C/C++ but one of them might be fast enough for your needs and would be easier to maintain:

```
# 1 Reduce
cumsum.bounded <- function(x, lower.bound = 0, upper.bound = 500) {
    bsum <- function(x, y) min(upper.bound, max(lower.bound, x+y))
    if (length(x) > 1) Reduce(bsum, x, acc = TRUE) else x
}

# 2 for loop
cumsum.bounded2 <- function(x, lower.bound = 0, upper.bound = 500) {
   if (length(x) > 1) 
      for(i in  2:length(x)) x[i] <- min(upper.bound, max(lower.bound, x[i] + x[i-1]))
   x
}
```

These may be need to be enhanced slightly if `x` has length 0 or 1 depending on how strict the requirements are.

Comment: They fail, if the first element is breaking the bound. `cumsum.bounded(c(-1,-1,3,4,5), 0, 10) => -1  0  3  7 10` and `cumsum.bounded(c(20,-1,3,4,5), 0, 10) => 20 10 10 10 10`

Comment: There is some question of whether such as edge case is really part of the question or whether the question is to keep the sums within the bounds but if it were desired it could easily be handled using `cumsum.bounded(c(0, x), 0, 10)[-1]` or by handling the initial valiue separately within the function.

Comment: Yeah sure. I find it still noteworthy. I was using it to calculate some kind of preference where I had a 1 for a choice matching my predicate and -1 if not. For some predicates the first choice was wrong, which led me to strange plots. If you are aware of it, it is easy to clean your data first.