# More efficient bounded cumulative sum

Tags: r, optimization

I have this R code which takes a lot of time to execute. How can I alter this code to make it run faster and more efficiently? It takes more than 12 minutes to execute.

```
m=matrix(0,10000,10000)
for (j in 1:10000) {
    for (i in 2:10000} {
       x=rnorm(1,0,1)
       m[j,i]=max(0,x-0.5+m[j,i-1])
    }
}
meanC=apply(m,2,mean)[2:10000]
meanC
```

Comment: There is a [Code Review Site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this type of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the rows of your matrix is a bounded cumulative sum of samples of the normal distribution minus 0.5, limiting so that your cumulative is never less than 0. Bounded cumulative sums have been addressed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262424/r-bounded-cumulative-sum/21264912) on SO, and I would suggest an approach using the Rcpp package:

```
library(Rcpp)
bounded.cumsum <- cppFunction(
"NumericVector cumsumBounded(NumericVector x, double low) {
  NumericVector res(x.size());
  double acc = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    acc += x[i];
    if (acc < low)  acc = low;
    res[i] = acc;
  }
  return res;
}")
m <- t(sapply(1:10000, function(r) c(0, bounded.cumsum(rnorm(9999, 0, 1)-0.5, 0))))
```

On my computer this takes 24 seconds, a 30x speedup.