# R: censored cumsum (censored random walk)

Tags: r, cumsum

I would like to be able to censor the generation of random walk data so that the walk never drops below a target value (generally 0). The following code accomplishes what I would want it to except I would rather have a function that works similar to cumsum that I can use to crunch through quickly millions of rows of such values such as `cumsum(x,min=0)`:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rep(0,length(x))
for(i in 2:length(x)) y[i] <- max(x[i]+y[i-1], 0)
plot(y, type='l')
```

[image: Censored Random Walk]

Comment: See [this relevant QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262424/r-bounded-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make your own function (copied from your code, but added initialization of `y[1]` to make it similar to `cumsum` behavior):

```
cumsum0<-function(x,min=0){
  y<-rep(0,length(x))
  y[1]<-max(x[1],0)
  for (i in 2:length(x)) y[i] <- max(x[i]+y[i-1], min)
  return(y)
}

x<-rnorm(1000)
plot(cumsum0(x),type="l")
```