# cumsum with upper and low limits? (R)

Tags: r

I am looking to figure out a way to cumsum a vector without going below or above a certain threshold.

For example

```
cumsum(2, 1, -4, 2, 2)
```

produces 2, 3, -1, 1, 3.

However, I want to add a lower limit of 0 and an upper limit of 3 so that an observation will never fall below or above those values. The result would be 2,3,0,2,3.

Comment: There are answers to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262424/bounded-cumulative-sum. Some of them involve `Rcpp` which is a more advanced topic, but one uses base R.

Comment: `pmin(3, pmax(0, cumsum(c(2, 1, -4, 2, 2))))`