# Calculating a modified passenger load with a condition that load cannot be negative using R tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently trying to calculate a passenger load for people getting on and off of public transportation vehicles. In other words, I want to know, for any given stop, how many people are on the vehicle.

I calculated the passenger load using the below code, but you'll notice that many of the load values are negative. This is a limitation of the data I have.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = structure(list(trip = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), stop = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), on = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
1), off = c(0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df = df  %>% 
  group_by(trip) %>%
  mutate(diff = on-off,
         load = cumsum(diff))
```

To deal with this, I want to make an assumption that would result in the load value never being negative. That is, there cannot be a case in which more people get off the vehicle than are on the vehicle in the first place.

If you just look at rows one and two, you see that 2 people get on the bus at stop 1, but 3 people get off at stop 2. This results in the load being -1, which, of course, is impossible.

I tried using the lag load values to create an "adjusted off" column that would use the previous stop's passenger load if the current count of disembarking passengers would cause the load to be negative:

```
df = df %>% 
  mutate(
  lag_load = lag(load),
  adj_off = case_when(off > lag_load ~ lag_load,
                                TRUE ~ off))
```

For this to work, I think the loads would have to be continuously recalculated.

I think I could get what I want by using a for loop, but I am looking for a solution that is more efficient because the data I have contains over 3 million rows, and the for loop will take a very long time. Any assistance in finding a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bounded cumulative sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262424/bounded-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the `cumsum` function to ignore cases where it would take the sum below zero.

```
cumsumpositive <- function(x){
  Reduce(\(a,b) if(a+b>=0) a+b else max(a,0) ,x,accumulate = TRUE)
}
```

Then, (keeping your `load` column for comparison):

```
df  %>% 
  group_by(trip) %>%
  mutate(diff = on-off,
         load = cumsum(diff),
         loadpositive = cumsumpositive(diff))

# Groups:   trip [2]
    trip  stop    on   off  diff  load loadpositive
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1     1     2     0     2     2            2
 2     1     2     0     3    -3    -1            2
 3     1     3     0     0     0    -1            2
 4     1     4     0     0     0    -1            2
 5     1     5     0     1    -1    -2            1
 6     2     1     3     0     3     3            3
 7     2     2     0     0     0     3            3
 8     2     3     0     4    -4    -1            3
 9     2     4     0     1    -1    -2            2
10     2     5     1     0     1    -1            3
```

This could be adapted for however you want to handle the negatives.

I tried this for 3 million rows and it takes on average about 5 seconds on my PC.  There may be a more efficient way.

(Edit - actually this question is a dupe of [Bounded cumulative sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262424/bounded-cumulative-sum), the answers describe using rcpp to make more efficient functions).